# LaTex enumitem - controlling alignment of items by level

Tags: enumitem

I am using the enumitem package for a document that will have 6 levels and have the following settings already:

```
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\setlistdepth{6}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\Alph*.}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\arabic*.}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label=\alph*.}
\setlist[enumerate,4]{label=(\arabic*)}
\setlist[enumerate,5]{label=(\alph*)}
\setlist[enumerate,6]{label=(\roman*)}
\renewlist{enumerate}{enumerate}{6}
\setlist[enumerate]{align=left, itemsep=1pt, parsep=3pt, topsep=1pt}
```

This is actually working as intended - up until I get to the 5th level.  At that point, the item indentation isn't sufficient and so the item label pushes the first line of the item paragraph farther to the right than the paragraph indent, causing the paragraph to not wrap around sufficiently, as in this case:
[image: sample]

Notice that the spacing is fine for 6. a. (1) but when it gets to (a), (b) and then  (i) and (ii) the item indentation for (a) is insufficient.  That causes the wrapping to be inadequate.  In (b) you can also see that this results in the (i) label being misaligned and then the same issue as with the item indent occurs for that item level as well.

What is the proper setting to ensure that the item indent has the proper length for the (a) and (i) levels (Levels 5 and 6 in this case)?

Note that I saw this in the documentation:
[image: enumitem documentation]

But when I tried adding itemindent=! to the \setlist where I also set the alignment, topsep, etc. it did not change anything.  I confirmed I had the latest version of enumitem since the docs say that this itemindent=! option is new in Version 3.0.

Here is a complete working example:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[
      height=9in,      % height of the text block
      width=7in,       % width of the text block
      top=78pt,        % distance of the text block from the top of the page
      headheight=36pt, % height for the header block
      headsep=12pt,    % distance from the header block to the text block
      heightrounded   % ensure an integer number of lines
      %,showframe       % show the main blocks
      ]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[default,scale=.9]{opensans}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\setlistdepth{6}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\Alph*.}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\arabic*.}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label=\alph*.}
\setlist[enumerate,4]{label=(\arabic*)}
\setlist[enumerate,5]{label=(\alph*)}
\setlist[enumerate,6]{label=(\roman*)}
\renewlist{enumerate}{enumerate}{6}
\setlist[enumerate]{align=left, itemsep=1pt, parsep=3pt, topsep=1pt, itemindent=!}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Terms and Conditions

    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Vacancy Condition

        \begin{enumerate}
        \item \textbf{Description of Terms}

              \begin{enumerate}
              \item As used in this Vacancy Condition, the term building and the
                term vacant have the meanings set forth in (1)(a) and (1)(b)
                below:

                    \begin{enumerate}
                    \item When this policy is issued to a tenant, and with respect to
                      that tenant's interest in Covered Property, building means the
                      unit or suite rented or leased to the tenant. Such building is
                      vacant when it does not contain enough business personal
                      property to conduct customary operations.

                    \item When this policy is issued to the owner or general lessee of a
                      building, building means the entire building. Such building is
                      vacant unless at least 31\% of its total square footage is:

                          \begin{enumerate}
                          \item Rented to a lessee or sub-lessee and used by the lessee or
                            sub-lessee to conduct its customary operations; and/or

                          \item Used by the building owner to conduct customary operations.
                          \end{enumerate}

                    \end{enumerate}

              \end{enumerate}

        \end{enumerate}

    \end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Please post a full compilable code that we can play with.

Comment: @Bernard I have added a working example above.

Answer (score 2):

I added the specification `leftmargin=*`. Is it more like you want?

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[
      height=9in, % height of the text block
      width=7in, % width of the text block
      top=78pt, % distance of the text block from the top of the page
      headheight=36pt, % height for the header block
      headsep=12pt, % distance from the header block to the text block
      heightrounded % ensure an integer number of lines
      %,showframe % show the main blocks
      ]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumerate}
%\usepackage[default,scale=.9]{opensans}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\setlistdepth{6}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\Alph*.}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\arabic*.}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label=\alph*.}
\setlist[enumerate,4]{label=(\arabic*)}
\setlist[enumerate,5]{label=(\alph*)}
\setlist[enumerate,6]{label=(\roman*)}
\renewlist{enumerate}{enumerate}{6}
\setlist[enumerate]{align=left, itemsep=1pt, parsep=3pt, topsep=1pt, itemindent=!, leftmargin=*}

\begin{document}
\sffamily
\begin{enumerate}
\item Terms and Conditions

    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Vacancy Condition

        \begin{enumerate}
        \item \textbf{Description of Terms}

              \begin{enumerate}
              \item As used in this Vacancy Condition, the term building and the
                term vacant have the meanings set forth in (1)(a) and (1)(b)
                below:

                    \begin{enumerate}
                    \item When this policy is issued to a tenant, and with respect to
                      that tenant's interest in Covered Property, building means the
                      unit or suite rented or leased to the tenant. Such building is
                      vacant when it does not contain enough business personal
                      property to conduct customary operations.

                    \item When this policy is issued to the owner or general lessee of a
                      building, building means the entire building. Such building is
                      vacant unless at least 31\% of its total square footage is:

                          \begin{enumerate}
                          \item Rented to a lessee or sub-lessee and used by the lessee or
                            sub-lessee to conduct its customary operations; and/or

                          \item Used by the building owner to conduct customary operations.
                          \end{enumerate}

                    \end{enumerate}

              \end{enumerate}

        \end{enumerate}

    \end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]